# CloudKit - How to Save Record If Not Exists

Tags: ios, icloud, ios8, cloudkit

I am trying to make a Record Type that contains unique values, and would act as the target reference objects to another Record Type. For example, Record Type - Movies would contain unique list of movies submitted by users. And FavoriteMovies would contain a Users reference and a Movies reference. Users could select from a list of existing Movies, or add new ones to it.

The problem happens if I create a new Movies record, while another user creates a new record with the same name (after I retrieved the list of movies, but before I attempt to add a new one). The two new records are considered different records with different recordIDs. This means that once I saved the new one, there will be two instances of Movies with the save name.

I'm not able to find a way to perform a Save If Not Exists type operation to the Movies Record Type. I could do a save in the completionBlock of a query, but those two actions would not be an atomic transaction to guarantee uniqueness. As far as I know this is also the case with chaining `CKQueryOperation` with `CKModifyRecordsOperation`.

Is there a way to insert a record only if the value does not exists in a single transaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correctly your use case, you can make movieRecord.recordID.recordName the movie's name and use `CKModifyRecordsOperation` with `savePolicy` `IfServerRecordUnchanged` to effectively Save If Not Exists. It would then return an error that you can ignore if you try to save a record that already exists on the server:

```
let saveRecordsOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation()
saveRecordsOperation.recordsToSave = [movieRecord]
saveRecordsOperation.savePolicy = .IfServerRecordUnchanged
```

With the savePolicy `IfServerRecordUnchanged` this operation will save a new Movie record if it doesn't exist yet on the server (Save If Not Exists) but will return the error below on any subsequent try to overwrite a Movie record that already exists on the server (provided it is not a newer modified version of a record that was fetched from the server):

```
<CKError 0x14d23980: "Server Record Changed" (14/2017); server message = "record to insert already exists">
```

You could deal with this conflict in the `perRecordCompletionBlock` but in your specific use case you can just do nothing about the conflict error so each Movie record will be the first saved record with that CKRecordID.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. I am creating a new instance of movieRecord to add to the list. If another user created a record with the same name (after I retrieved the list of movies, but before I attempt to add a new one), they are considered different records since they have different recordIDs. This means that even though my savePolicy is set to IfServerRecordUnchanged, the operation does not throw an error. Instead I would see two different records with the same name.

Comment: Got it. It would work if you made movieRecord.recordID.recordName the movie's name. I have a similar use case using the Public Database and that's what I am doing to keep public records unique. I made an edit to the answer to note that assumption.

Comment: Good idea, this work around will do it for me. Thanks!